# How can I limit the number of rows that a KendoUI Grid can have?

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a simple kendo UI grid which is supposed to have a maximum of only 5 rows. Is there any configuration property that I can use to limit the rows, or should I write some simple custom logic to examine my data source and prevent adding more than 5 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following `kendoGrid` definition:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource:stocksDataSource,
    columns   :[
        { field:"col1", title:"Column 1" },
        { field:"col2", title:"Column 2" },
        { field:"col3", title:"Column 3" }
    ],
    toolbar   :[
        { name      :"create", className :"k-grid-add2" }
    ],
    editable  :true
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Where I added a `create` button in the toolbar **but** redefined its `className` to `k-grid-add2`. Then I add trap the `click` event on this button as follow:

```
$(".k-grid-add2", grid.element).bind("click", function (ev) {
    console.log("adding!");
    if (grid.dataSource.data().length < 5) {
        grid.addRow();
    } else {
        alert("Too many, sorry!")
    }
});
```

Where I check the number of rows and if there is less than 5 then I invoke `grid.addRow()` otherwise I alert user that there are too many rows.

Comment: return false;  //after if else in case of batch mode

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that the page size should be limited to 5 rows, then you can set the `pageSize` option on the datasource:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   dataSource: {
       pageSize: 5
   }
});
```

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#pageablepagesize-number

Comment: No, I actually want the grid to have only 5 rows at all times and come to think of it, I guess such a thing should be done with my own logic on the datasource :)

But thanks ...!

Comment: I was just wondering if I really should use this line : 


if($("#divProductsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length < 5) 

{// do something }

Comment: No, there is no such option (afaik).

Comment: Is a grid where you can add rows? If so, your solution does not prevent adding rows but rather check if the number of rows is less than 5. The solution is similar but you need to intercept `add` event and `grid.addRow` if there are less than 5 rows.

Comment: @Sandeep You're right, then it should be done before adding the data source. How does your data source look like? Is it an array, list, something else?

Comment: Mario and Emiliano - yup, you are both right that is exactly how I am doing it now.

My datasource would be a json array.

Thanks for the help !